# Predicting that the program will crash

Tags: c#, c++, crash

I've been using Google Chrome for a while now and I noticed that it features very elegant crash control.

Just before crashing, google chrome gave a message saying "*Woah! Google Chrome has crashed. Restart now?*". And right after, I'd get a standard Windows XP "This program has encountered a problem and needs to close." with the "Debug", "Don't send" and "Send Error Report" buttons.

My question is how can you program your compiled application to detect a crash condition in advance? If you have knowledge of how to do it in any programming language / platform would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Upon first glance at this question, I wondered if this was going to be  about whether Google had resolved the Halting Problem...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google Chrome uses a technique (often called *process separation*) where the 'host' UI manages child processes that it can detect becoming unresponsive (or worse, throwing an error and closing). It starts a new process for each tab you open.

[Here's an article](http://blog.marcchung.com/2008/09/05/chromes-process-model-explained.html) describing this in a bit more detail.

Using .net's [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, you can start processes, check if they're responsive and even kill them.

If you want to embed a process' window within your own, you can use platform functions such as [SetParent](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html) to move one window within another. I'm afraid I'm not aware of a managed alternative to SetParent when working with Forms, but I suspect one exists so it's worth searching for that before using SetParent.

If the host process crashes, simply using something like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` will allow you to receive a notification that a top-level exception has occurred, but by this stage you're unlikely to be able to predict the state of objects within your app and restarting (along with some logging and a notification to the user) is probably your only sensible option.

Handling top-level exceptions is [covered in detail here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/04/18/ui-exception-handling-vs-appdomain-exceptions.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

I don't know Google's code so I am speculating.  Google Chrome probably isn't predicting that it will crash, but detecting that it has crashed.

In Windows you can do this by providing a handler for all unhandled exceptions.  In this handler you might do things such as restart the application, create a minidump file, etc.

Take a look at [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx) for one method.

Comment: Note that the reason the Windows debug window comes up afterwards is that google goes ahead and throws the error to the OS after it is done with it.

Comment: Sort of.  It's detecting that one of its child processes crashed.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET, you can hook up to the System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Your code would look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += MyUnhandledExceptionHandler;

        // start rest of application
    }

    private static void MyUnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your app is crashing.  Watch out!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice - I always like seeing some code samples when someone answers a question.

Comment: You need to do more than that, see http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/08/global-exception-handling-net-v11-part.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a restart API. [Daniel Moth has blogged about it here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2009/03/internet-explorer-8-using-restart-apis.html) and [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/03/please-use-restart-api-to-its-full.html). Please note I am not saying this is the way Google Chrome works, just that it is something you might want to look into.

I believe you could also load bits of the app in seperate [App Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). I believe this is what the .NET 3.5 [Addin framework uses](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/new-net-35-feat.html), though I can't say I've ever used it (merely read about it). Looks like Daniel has [blogged about this too](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/03/systemaddin.html).